# What does a professor aim at when talking about communication?

Tags: phd, collaboration, communication, lab-meeting

I am a PhD student at a good university in the US. I am good at my work and do my assigned tasks well. But this is the second time I heard from the second professor that I should communicate more with the other students and I am not good at it!

I don't know what they mean? I have a good relationship with the other students and I think I do work better than them. Yes, they talk more to each other but not about work, rather about anything outside of the work. I think it's not worth to spend time on those kind of talks.

Should I really engage in non-work-related discussions to be considered as a communicative student?

It's so strange to me and I don't know what to do or how to ask more about my problem from the professors if they tell me such a thing?

Comment: I don't think this is something that anyone here can answer. The best way to find out what your advisor is looking for is for you talk to them, and politely ask them to clarify what they want. You can even mention what you say here (just try to be polite in how you phrase it) -- you don't know exactly what they mean, and you don't feel the need to talk about non-work topics. Your advisor shouldn't require that you talk about non-work related topics at work, if you don't want to. (Although, I suspect you will find that is not what they are asking you to do, if you talk with them).

Answer (score 2):

One can't infer from your question what your adviser meant. But they might have meant both talking about work and non-work matters.

Even if your work is good, so far, you won't ever do great work without collaborators. You get collaborators by talking to people about research. Being able to communicate ideas effectively is a great skill to have. It will also help you get a better job down the road and being a good teacher if you need to teach.

You also need to be more open to talk to people (not necessarily your colleagues about subjects unrelated to work. It will help improve your English.

The greatest skill you get by talking to people is the skill to listen patiently to what others have to say. It will help in your personal life, and in your research life. Many very good scientists are terrible communicators. But if you work with them, you need to learn how to talk to them. If you learn how to listen, and how to ask the right questions, you can collaborate effectively with them. If not, they will give up on you, just as you intend to give up on your colleagues right now.

Another comment is that is nearly impossible to build up relationships with people you don't talk to. They need to trust you before collaborating with you. If you stay in academia, you'll need to get grants, create a research group, participate in larger projects. Your colleagues from now will likely be your partners at some point in the future. They need to know that you do quality research work and you're happy to collaborate with them.

Finally, if communicating is taking a toll on you, it is not wrong to let people know you are not talking too much because of that. Most people will understand, and some might even appreciate that you're trying even if it is hard for you.